# Check whether content already sent in PHP

Tags: php, http-headers

Is there a smart way to check whether output has already been sent to the browser and sending a header would generate a PHP_WARNING?

Obviously there's the alternative of using an output buffer, but that's not always an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the headers_sent() method. This because before anything is outputted, the headers will be send first.

Answer (score 2):

[headers_sent()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) does a poor job and doesn't always return TRUE in case the output has been sent (e.g. notices and warnings).

As an alternative, I use this:

```
<?php

$obStatus = ob_get_status();

if ($obStatus['buffer_used'] > 0) {
    echo 'Content was sent';
} else {
    echo 'Content was NOT sent';
}
```

Comment: This is correct when notices and warnings are generated by xdebug

Answer (score -1):

If all you want is to hide the warning, just turn off [error reporting](http://www.php.net/error_reporting):

```
$old_er = error_reporting(0);

header(...)

error_reporting($old_er);
```

Or, you can redirect PHP errors and warnings to a log file (which is preferable in production, IMO).